# How to create a specific amount of invite links that can only be used once for a Discord server in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I am new to working with Discord servers and I would like to make a private Discord server where only users that I invite can join. I read about a few ways that this can be achieved, but none of them are really what I have in mind. I was thinking about creating a Discord application that generated a specific amount of invite links to my server which can only be used once.

This means that if I want to invite 50 people to my Discord server, I would create 50 invite links that can only be used once so that I make sure that only the people I invite will join. I would like to put all of these links in an external text file so that I will later be able to work with them and eventually send them to people by email. In other words, I don't need to create a bot, but rather just use Python and the discord.py module to achieve all this outside of Discord.

I saw [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#discord.Client.create_invite) on the discord.py documentation which looks something like what I need, but I don't really understand how that would work.

I can almost only find tutorials on how to create bots, on the Discord server itself, but that is not what I need. Would anyone be able to help me out?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you ever turn this into a bot? I've come up against a similar issue. I'm certainly not against using the below Python to achieve the goal, but if there's a ready-made solution I'd try that first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import discord

token = 'bot_token_goes_here'
client = discord.Client()
number_of_links = input('How many links do you want to create? ') 

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    g = client.guilds[guild_number goes here] # Choose the guild/server you want to use 
    c = g.get_channel(channel_id_goes_here) # Get channel ID
    invites = await discord.abc.GuildChannel.invites(c) # list of all the invites in the server

    while len(invites) < int(number_of_links):
        print('CREATING INVITES')
        for i in range(int(number_of_links)): # Create as many links as needed
            i = await discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite(c, max_uses=1, max_age=0, unique=True) # Create the invite link
        break

    print('Finished. Exiting soon...')
    exit()

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some quick modifications to FedeCuci's script, with the following differences:

- Script asks for the total number of *new* invites you want, rather than depending on previously created invites
- Script outputs the new invites to console
- Does not throw an exception
- Compatible with new intents API
- Some additional debugging output

For either script, you will need to install [discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/), then run the script with `python3`.  Don't forget to update the token & ID's as needed, and setup/join the bot to your target server via [Discord's developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/).  It will need permissions for `Create Instant Invite` and `Read Messages/View Channels`

```py
from discord.utils import get
import discord

token = 'bot-token-goes-here' # <-- fill this in
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.invites = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
guild_id = guild-id-goes-here # <-- fill this in
number_of_links = input('How many links do you want to create? ')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is up and running.')
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

    g = client.get_guild(int(guild_id))
    print(f'Guild: {g.name}')
    c = g.get_channel(channel-id-goes-here) # <-- fill this in
    print(f'Channel: #{c}')
    invites = []

    print('CREATING INVITES')

    for i in range(int(number_of_links)):
        invite = await g.text_channels[0].create_invite(max_uses=1, max_age=0, unique=True)
        print(f'{invite}')

    print('Finished. Exiting soon...')
    await client.close()

client.run(token)
```